# I use the poi to get the backgroundcolor,but it get same argbhex by different color

Tags: excel, apache-poi

this is my test class:

```
public class testReadExcel {
public static void readExcel () throws Exception {
String path = "d:\\字体颜色1.xlsx";
File file = new File(path);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
int numbersheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
int cols = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
for(int i = 0; i<cols;i++) {
Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    int cellnumber = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    for(int j = 0;j<cellnumber;j++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
        CellStyle cellstyle1 = ((XSSFCell)cell).getCellStyle();
        XSSFCellStyle cellstyle = (XSSFCellStyle)cellstyle1;    
        XSSFColor b = cellstyle.getFillForegroundXSSFColor();
        XSSFColor d = cellstyle.getFillBackgroundXSSFColor();
            String c =  b.getARGBHex();
            String e =  d.getARGBHex();
        System.out.println("c   "+c);
        System.out.println("e   "+e);
    }
}

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    readExcel();
```

and this is the color i used：

[image]

one color is `#E46D0A` ,the another is `#F79646`.
but when i get the color ,all of them become `#F79646`

```
c   FFF79646

e   null

c   FFF79646

e   null
```

This is the code's console ,how to get the right color?

Comment: sorry,I just show the console with problem.and this is the complete console

    c   FFFF0000
    e   null
c   FFF79646
e   null
c   FFF79646
e   null
c   FFFFFFCC
e   null
c   FFFFFFCC
e   null
c   FFFFFFCC
e   null

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing since your screenshot shows 6 cells which all should be processed by your code. But your shown result only shows results for two cells. I suspect this are the both first cells in your screenshot? If so, then the only reason for this output can be that the second cell has additional conditional formatting having pattern formatting set. So it has both, a cell style having fill formatting and the conditional formatting having pattern formatting. If this is the case, then the fill format of the conditional formatting is visible if the condition of the conditional formatting is fulfilled. Only if the condition of the conditional formatting is not fulfilled, then the cell style's fill format will be visible.

If the requirement is to get the visible fill color always, independent of whether it comes from cell style or conditional formatting, then this is a very expensive task. One would must test for each cell whether it has a conditional formatting and whether the condition is fulfilled.

The following complete code at least checks for each cell whether it has a conditional formatting having pattern formatting. If so, it prints all background colors of all conditional formattings which are applied to the cell. It does not check whether the condition is fulfilled or not. This is the expensive part of the task that nor is ToDo.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ConditionalFormatting;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ReadExcelCellStyleFillColors {

 static List<PatternFormatting> getConditionalPatternFormatting(Cell cell) {
  List<PatternFormatting> patternFormattings = new ArrayList<PatternFormatting>();
  Sheet sheet = cell.getSheet();
  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
  for (int i = 0; i < sheetCF.getNumConditionalFormattings(); i++) {
   ConditionalFormatting conditionalFormatting = sheetCF.getConditionalFormattingAt(i);
   CellRangeAddress[] cellRangeAdresses = conditionalFormatting.getFormattingRanges();
   for (CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress : cellRangeAdresses) {
    if (cellRangeAddress.isInRange(cell)) {
     for (int j = 0; j < conditionalFormatting.getNumberOfRules(); j++) {
      ConditionalFormattingRule cFRule = conditionalFormatting.getRule(j);
      PatternFormatting patternFormatting = cFRule.getPatternFormatting();
      if (patternFormatting != null) patternFormattings.add(patternFormatting);
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return patternFormattings;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelExample.xlsx"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    System.out.println("This is cell " + new CellAddress(cell));

    List<PatternFormatting> patternFormattings = getConditionalPatternFormatting(cell);
    if (patternFormattings.size() > 0) {
     System.out.println("This cell has conditional pattern formattings having background colors:");
     for (PatternFormatting patternFormatting : patternFormattings) {
      Color patternBGColor = patternFormatting.getFillBackgroundColorColor();
      System.out.println(patternBGColor);
      if (patternBGColor instanceof ExtendedColor) {
       ExtendedColor extColor = (ExtendedColor)patternBGColor;
       if (extColor.isThemed()) {
        System.out.println("Theme color with index: " + extColor.getTheme());
       } else {
        System.out.println(extColor.getARGBHex());
       }
      }
     }
    }

    CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
    Color fillFGColor = cellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor();
    System.out.println("This cell has fill foreground color:");
    System.out.println(fillFGColor);
    if (fillFGColor instanceof ExtendedColor) {
     ExtendedColor extColor = (ExtendedColor)fillFGColor;
     System.out.println(extColor.getARGBHex());
    }

    System.out.println();
   }
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```